# Mockito stubbing is not working when service class method is called

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I tried to stub a set of data suppose to be return by a specific service method to a method present in controller so I need to stub for three methods call (getLopaReConfigPath,getBASeatKit and getBAColumnSeatKit) and it is working for only one method and not working for rest of the methods!!!

Following is the code of Controller method to be tested

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSeatLayoutDisplay", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody JSONObject getSeatLayoutDisplay(@RequestBody String params) {

        JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject  combinedJson = new JSONObject();

        try {
            JsonObject gsonData = parseRequestDataToJson(params);

            StringBuffer filePathBuf = new StringBuffer(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath(gsonData.get("carrierName").getAsString(), gsonData.get("dbName").getAsString()));
            filePathBuf.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("INPUT"));

            String seatKitXmlFilePath = filePathBuf.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();
            String columnXMl = filePathBuf.append(Constants.COLUMN_XML_FILENAME).toString();

            BASeatKitInfo seatKitInfo = lopaReConfigService.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);
            KitLayout columnSeatKitLeft = lopaReConfigService.getBAColumnSeatKit(gsonData.get("filepath").getAsString(),columnXMl);

            combinedJson.put("kitLayoutCenter", columnSeatKitLeft);
            combinedJson.put("kitInfo", seatKitInfo);

            resultJson.put("lopaReconfig",combinedJson);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(" Failed due to " + e);

        }
        return resultJson;

    }
```

following is the test case I have returned

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LopaReConfigControllerTest {


    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

    // Application dependency 

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Mock
    LopaReConfigService lopaReConfigService;

    @Mock
    CommonUtil commonUtil;

    @Mock
    ProcessLopaReconfigFile processLopaReconfigFile;

    @Mock
    DBImportRepository dbImportRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    MockHttpSession session;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @InjectMocks
    LopaReConfigController lopaReConfigController;

    @Mock
    UserSessionPool sessionPool;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(lopaReConfigController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getSeatLayoutDisplay() throws Exception {

    // Construct JSON data to pass as parameter

        BASeatkitDataFeeder seatKitDataFeeder = new BASeatkitDataFeeder();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CommonUtil util = new CommonUtil();
        StringBuffer filePathBuff = new StringBuffer();

        filePathBuff.append(util.getLopaReConfigPath("ABC-300ER", "ABC-300ER-B777-v300B"));
        filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("INPUT"));

    seatKitDataFeeder.setBuildVersion("Base");
    seatKitDataFeeder.setCarrierName("ABC-300ER");
    seatKitDataFeeder.setDbId("1558");
    seatKitDataFeeder.setDbName("ABC-300ER-B777-v300B");
    seatKitDataFeeder.setSessionId(session.getId());
    seatKitDataFeeder.setFilepath(filePathBuff.toString());

    String seatKitXmlFilePath = filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();
    String columnXMl = filePathBuff.append(Constants.COLUMN_XML_FILENAME).toString();   

    LopaReConfigRepositoryImpl lopaImpl = new LopaReConfigRepositoryImpl();

    BASeatKitInfo BAinfo = lopaImpl.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);
    KitLayout kitLayout = lopaImpl.getBAColumnSeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath+Constants.SEATKIT_COLUMN_XML_FILENAME,columnXMl);

    //Stub the result whaen methods get called

        Mockito.when(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath("ABC-300ER", "ABC-300ER-B777-v300B")).thenReturn(filePathBuff.toString()); // working fine
        Mockito.when(lopaReConfigService.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath)).thenReturn(BAinfo); // not stubbing the BAinfo object when method is called
        Mockito.when(lopaReConfigService.getBAColumnSeatKit("","")).thenReturn(kitLayout); // not stubbing the kitLayout object when method is called

        // Test method logic 

    mvc.perform(post("/getSeatLayoutDisplay")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(jsonStub))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()) // After hitting specific URL/URI check the status code fall under 200 series
        .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)); // Check the return statement is JSON

    // Verify that the the lopaReConfigService is called only once during execution.

    verify(lopaReConfigService, times(0)).getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);
    verify(lopaReConfigService, times(0)).getBAColumnSeatKit(seatKitDataFeeder.getFilepath(),columnXMl);
    }
}
```

The problem is I am trying to stub the objects for 3 methods but mockito setting the first method result properly when its get called but same thing is not happening for other two methods

I have tried to do with Matcher and by overriding equals and hashcode methods but still it doesn’t helped me out.

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

---

Stubbing works fine with following method

```
 Mockito.when(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath("ABC-300ER", "ABC-300ER-B777-v300B")).thenReturn(filePathBuff.toString()); // working fine
```

Not working for following methods

```
Mockito.when(lopaReConfigService.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath)).thenReturn(BAinfo); // not stubbing the BAinfo object when method is called
        Mockito.when(lopaReConfigService.getBAColumnSeatKit("","")).thenReturn(kitLayout); // not stubbing the kitLayout object when method is called
```

Comment: what is the error you getting? post the stack trace as well.

Comment: Jobin I am not getting any error, when ever controller call a service methods are returning null value

Comment: is this returning valid output `lopaImpl.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);` ?

Comment: I use the Mockito.when to stub the data which suppose to feed by the service layer methods in actual execution of the method, hear just I wanted to simulate the same to test the part of a code present in controller

Comment: what kind of test you are writing is this Unit Test or Integration Test?
and what is value of `lopaImpl.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);` in test?

Comment: No because controller method responsible to write the data in the form of JSON, because service methods are returning the null value it is just appending those to specific key and returning the value

Comment: I wanted to do unit testing and lopaImpl.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath); method will gives the JSON string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131044/discussion-between-jobin-and-rajesh-hatwar).

Comment: For which method does stubbing work and for which it doesn't? Could you please extend your question and point at the methods that where stubbing doesn't work?

Comment: Serghey Bishyr  By the help of Jobin I have solved the problem please have look into above comment by Jobin. I am just waiting for Jobin to write his answer for this post so that I can contribute some good points to him!

Answer (score 0):

you are not feeding the when the same parameters in the code and the test code.

in the test seatKitXmlFilePath is different than the one in tested code

in the test you do

```
StringBuffer filePathBuff = new StringBuffer();
filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();
String seatKitXmlFilePath = filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();
```

in the tested code

```
StringBuffer filePathBuf = new StringBuffer(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath(gsonData.get("carrierName").getAsString(), gsonData.get("dbName").getAsString()));
filePathBuf.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();
String seatKitXmlFilePath = filePathBuf.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();
```

if you need it to match anything just use anyString()

that way it will match on any string

so your test code can have

```
Mockito.when(lopaReConfigService.getBASeatKit(anyString())).thenReturn(BAinfo); // not stubbing the BAinfo object when method is called
        Mockito.when(lopaReConfigService.getBAColumnSeatKit(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(kitLayout);
```

and in this case it should match